# Upon updating, how to compare a model instance with its former state

Tags: model-view-controller, sails.js, lifecycle

I'm using Sails.js v0.10.5, but this probably applies to more general MVC lifecycle logics (Ruby on Rails?).

I have two models, say `Foo` and `Baz`, linked with a one-to-one association.
Each time that data in a `Foo` instance changes, some heavy operations must be carried out on a `Baz` model instance, like the `costlyRoutine`method shown below.

```
// api/model/Foo.js

module.exports {
  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    data: 'json',
    baz: {
      model: 'Baz'
    }
  },

  updateBaz: function(criteria,cb) {
    Foo.findOne( criteria, function(err,foo) {
      Baz.findOne( foo.baz, function(err,baz) {
        baz.data = costlyRoutine( foo.data ); // or whatever
        cb();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Upon updating an instance of `Foo`, it therefore makes sense to first test whether `data` has changed from old object to new. It could be that just `name` needs to be updated, in which case I'd like to avoid the heavy computation.

When is it best to make that check?

I'm thinking of the `beforeUpdate` callback, but it will require calling something like `Foo.findOne(criteria)` to retrieve the current `data` object. Inefficient? Sub-optimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only optimization I could think of:

> You could call `costlyRoutine` iff relevant fields are being updated.

Apart from that, you could try to cache `Foo` (using some locality of reference caching, like paging). But that depends on your use case.

Perfect optimization would be really like trying to look into the future :D

Comment: I'll bundle this into a `needsBazBeUpdated` routine and use it in `Foo`'s `beforeUpdate`. Any reference on reference caching you could suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You might save a little by using the `afterUpdate` callback, which would have the `Foo` object already loaded so you can save a call.

```
// api/model/Foo.js

module.exports {
  attributes: {
    ...
  },

  afterUpdate: function(foo,cb) {
    Baz.findOne( foo.baz, function(err,baz) {
      baz.data = costlyRoutine( foo.data ); // or whatever
      cb();
    });
  }
}
```

Otherwise as [myusuf aswered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27231766/1494833), if you only need to update based on relevant fields, then you can tap into it in the `beforeUpdate` callback.

Btw, instance functions should be defined inside `attributes` prop, lifecycle callbacks outside.

Comment: On the instance functions, agreed — but `updateBaz` was neither an instance function nor a lifecycle callback.

Comment: As for your answer, my problem is precisely to avoid doing this systematically. I'll go for @myusuf's answer, adding that it must be used within `beforeUpdate` (the only place where I still can compare new fields with those in the current record)

Comment: Sure. But sails doesn't offer any way of accessing the model being updated in `beforeUpdate`, so that's why I suggested going for `afterUpdate`. I hope @myusuf can explain about the caching so there might be a solution that way.

Comment: To summarize, in `beforeUpdate` there's no access to the model instance about to be updated, while in `afterUpdate` there's no access to the earlier state of the record just updated.